# How to refresh tableview after adding the new data in JavaFx

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, auto-update

I am currently working on JAVA FX application to fetch the user's information from JIRA REST API. I want to have a refresh button and on clicking it,the table view must be shown with the newly added data.
Please have a look at the code.
My POJO class
public class Issues {

```
private String jiraKey;
private String jiraSummary;
private String jiraPriority;
private String jiraAssignee;
private String jiraIssueType;
private Hyperlink hyperLink;
private String loghours;
private String commentLogHours;

public Issues(String jiraKey, String jiraSummary, String jiraPriority, String jiraAssignee, String jiraIssueType) {
    super();
    this.hyperLink = new Hyperlink(jiraKey);
    this.jiraSummary = jiraSummary;
    this.jiraPriority = jiraPriority;
    this.jiraAssignee = jiraAssignee;
    this.jiraIssueType = jiraIssueType;
    this.hyperLink = hyperLink;
    this.loghours = loghours;
    this.commentLogHours = commentLogHours;
}

public String getJiraKey() {
    return jiraKey;
}

public void setJiraKey(String jiraKey) {
    this.jiraKey = jiraKey;
}

//getters and setters
```

}

My Observable list method which populates the data to table

```
Class ABC{
       public ObservableList<Issues> issueJsonList(){
        // A processed arraylist 
        ObservableList<Issues> data = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        return data;
      }
   }
```

Here's my tableview code.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public TableView<Issues> initTable() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        TableView<Issues> table = new TableView<Issues>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        TableColumn<Issues, Hyperlink> jiraKey = new TableColumn<>(keyField);
        jiraKey.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("hyperLink"));
        jiraKey.setCellFactory(new HyperlinkCell());
        TableColumn jiraPriority = new TableColumn(priorityField);
        TableColumn jiraIssueType = new TableColumn(issueTypeField);
        TableColumn jiraSummary = new TableColumn(summaryField);
        TableColumn jiraAssignee = new TableColumn(assigneeField);
        TableColumn workLogCol = new TableColumn(workLogField);
        TableColumn timeSpent = new TableColumn(timeSpentField);
        TableColumn commentTimeLog = new TableColumn(commentField);
        workLogCol.getColumns().addAll(timeSpent, commentTimeLog);
        jiraSummary.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("jiraSummary"));
        jiraIssueType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("jiraIssueType"));
        jiraPriority.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("jiraPriority"));
        jiraAssignee.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("jiraAssignee"));
        timeSpent.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("getTimeSpent"));
        timeSpent.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        commentTimeLog.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("getComment"));
        commentTimeLog.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        timeSpent.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<JiraAuth, String>>() {
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<JiraAuth, String> t) {
                JiraAuth.setTimeSpent(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });
        commentTimeLog.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        commentTimeLog.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<JiraAuth, String>>() {
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<JiraAuth, String> t) {
                JiraAuth.setWorkLogComment(t.getNewValue());
                int i = t.getTablePosition().getRow();
                String abc = table.getColumns().get(0).getCellData(i).toString();
                String finalStr = abc.substring(abc.indexOf("]") + 1);
                JiraAuth.setWorkLogJiraKey(finalStr);
            }
        });
        table.getColumns().setAll(jiraKey, jiraSummary, jiraPriority, jiraAssignee, jiraIssueType);
        IssuesJsonParser issueObject = new IssuesJsonParser();
        ObservableList<Issues> data = issueObject.issueJsonList();
        table.setItems(data);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        return table;
    }
```

upon calling the refresh button,

```
buttons[0] = new Button("Refresh");
buttons[0].setOnAction(event->{
initTable().refresh();
});
```

nothing happens. Please help!!

Comment: All you need to do is add the new data to the backing list, i.e. `data.add(...)`. There should be no need to call `refresh()` when new items are added to that list.

Comment: @James_D can you please elaborate>

Comment: There is really nothing more to elaborate on. Calling `refresh()` is only necessary if you are not using Java properties in your model class and the values of some data in existing elements in the table have changed. If you are adding or removing my elements from the table's backing list, it will automatically update. You should post a [MCVE] if it is not updating for you.